# ssh to a computer run a command and mail the result

Tags: networking, bash, ssh, email

This is the scenario 
 I have a cluster in university that is not connected to Internet.
 I have another computer that is connected to Internet.

I want to ssh via computer to cluster and execute a command and get result and mail to me so i can check status from home.
means i need a bash-script that ssh to cluster login with password and run a command and get result and mail me the result.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly could do this with a python code:

```
import paramiko
import time
import os


def touch(path):
    with open(path, 'a'):
        os.utime(path, None)


ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('ip', port=port, username='USER', password='PASS',
            key_filename='OPTIONAL Address to private Key')

baseCommand = "command"
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('some command')
print(stdout.readlines())
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(baseCommand + 'ls')
print(stdout.readlines())

#for copy file

localpath = "local paths" + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S") + ".sql"; # add a date name for file
remotepath = "remote path"
touch(localpath);
sftp.get(remotepath, localpath) # download the file

sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

Comment: this code connect and exec few commands and download a file